# Hexagon not regular

Tags: geometry

Plotting the set:

$$ \small 
\left\{ 
(x,\,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 
x + \frac{3}{2} \le y \le x + 2, \;
3\,x \le y \le 3\,x + 1, \;
-2\,x + 3 \le y \le -2\,x + 4 
\right\} $$

the following hexagon is obtained:

[image]

which is characterized by sides that are two to two parallel, but not congruent.

I noticed that the lines that connect the midpoints of the parallel sides pass through a single point. I'm thinking how to proof this fact with *synthetic geometry*, but nothing comes to mind of elementary. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old problem. It appeared e.g. in [Prasolov's book](http://e.math.hr/afine/planegeo.pdf) as problem 5.80.

Below I present a proof I came up with once; it assumes familiarity with some projective geometry though.

Let $ABCDEF$ be a hexagon whose pairs of opposite sides are parallel. Note that $X:=AB \cap DE, Y:=BC \cap EF, Z:=CD \cap FA$ are points at infinity, and therefore are collinear (they lie on the line in the infinity). By Pascal theorem, $ABCDEF$ is inscribed in a conic.

Denoting the midpoints of $AB$ and $DE$ by $K$ and $L$, respectively, we see that quadruples $(A,B,X,K)$, $(D,E,X,L)$ are harmonic. It follows that $KL$ is the polar line of $X$ with respect to the circumconic of $ABCDEF$. Hence, the pole of the line in infinity lies on $KL$. An analogous argument shows that the other two lines determined by the midpoints of opposite sides of $ABCDEF$ pass through the pole of the line in infinity, which solves the problem.

Comment: @TeM Check out my edited answer. I have added a source of this problem, you can find an elementary solution there.